Make buttons to switch between 12 and 24 hour time that saves to localstorage
I have a clock in my website, and I would like to add a button or switch into settings that switches the time from 12 hour and 24 hour and vice versa.
My problem is that I have no idea where to connect the setClockStyle in the clock.js
const displayTime = document.querySelector(".display-time");

function showTime() {
  let time = new Date();

  displayTime.innerText = time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour12: true,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  });

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}

showTime();

function updateDate() {
  let today = new Date();
  let dayName = today.getDay(),
    dayNum = today.getDate();
  const IDCollection = ["daynum"];
  const val = [dayNum];

  for (let i = 0; i < IDCollection.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(IDCollection[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = val[i];
  }
}

updateDate();

And buttons
<div class="section-title">Clock Style</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button" onclick="setClockStyle('12')">12hr</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="setClockStyle('24')">24hr</button>
</div>
  


Please edit your question and 1) add a tag for the coding language you're using, 2) add in the setClockStyle code segment, 3) remove the code segments that don't directly pertain to the problem and 4) add debugging details. So far, you've just told us what you want.  You haven't given us any details about what problem or error you're encountering with your code.

Use setInterval() to execute something repeatedly, rather than calling setTimeout() at the end of the function to call itself again.

Pls provide your HTML to make a reproducible snippet

by the way, you forgot to show your setClockStyle function

Use a global variable to hold the flag for 12 or 24-hour time. Then use that in showTime().
let hour12 = true;

function showTime() {
  let time = new Date();

  displayTime.innerText = time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour12: hour12,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  });

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}

Then setClockStyle() can simply set the variable appropriately:
function setClockStyle(style) {
    hour12 = style == '12';
}


There are many ways to approach this. One is to use radio buttons to set the hour12 value, with the default checked radio setting the default hour12 value. Otherwise global variables can be held in a closure using an IIFE, e.g.


window.onload = function() {
  // get the radios
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="12or24"]');
  // add listeners
  inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', updateClock));
  // initialise clock using checked radio
  updateClock.call([...inputs].find(input => input.checked));
}

// Use IIFE to hold otherwise global variables
const updateClock = (function() {

  let timeoutId, hour12;

  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    // If *hour12 attribute available, reset hour12
    if (this && this.dataset && this.dataset.hour12) {
      hour12 = this.dataset.hour12 == 'true';
    }
    let options = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
      hour12: hour12
    };
    document.querySelector('#clock').innerText = new Date().toLocaleString('en-gb', options);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
  }
})();
<div>
  <input name="12or24" type="radio" data-hour12="true">12 hour</input>
  <input name="12or24" type="radio" data-hour12="false" checked>24 hour</input>
  <br>
  <p id="clock"></p>
</div>



Using setTimeout to run the clock causes it to slowly drift so it will skip a second every now and then. I'd rather call the function using setInterval with an interval set to just after the next full second. E.g.
(Date.now() % 1000) + 20

will return a value 20 milliseconds after the next full second.

I made 2 snippets the first is without using setClockStyle function (you don't really need) and then adding argument 'format' in your function (will be either true or false for hour12).


const displayTime1 = document.querySelector(".display-time-one");




function showTime1(format) {
  let time = new Date();

  displayTime1.innerText = time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour12: format,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  });

}

showTime1(true);
<div class="section-title">Clock Style</div>

<div class="display-time-one"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button" onclick="showTime1(true)">12hr</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="showTime1(false)">24hr</button>

</div>



The second one with using setClockStyle that will take the argument as true or false and pass it to showtime function.


const displayTime2 = document.querySelector(".display-time-two");

function setClockStyle(arg){
    showTime2(arg)
}

function showTime2(format) {
      let time = new Date();
      displayTime2.innerText = time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour12: format,
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit'
    });
  
  }
setClockStyle(true)
<div class="section-title">Clock Style</div>

<div class="display-time-two"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button" onclick="setClockStyle(true)">12hr</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="setClockStyle(false)">24hr</button>
</div>




They want a clock that updates.

Similar to what i tried to make some time ago with another site, but the only thing remaining is the localstorage part

@soyuzlord I have a weird behaviour when I use localstorage to keep format when refreshing page for example. I just can't seem to change the clock format even if 'format' inside showtime2 is changed (you need here gifted JS with serious skills) good luck and if you solve it pls post solution.

You can check this codepen

@Mehdi its a good implementation, but when i put it into a site to test, the localstorage is not working. the clock also takes a bit to load

@soyuzlord yes exactly this snipet shows that even though the value is updated inside showtime still it is not working. I think you need callback here like RobG answer it might bé working
